# How do I view webpages using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a project, and needed some help. I need to view the search results from Google for a user input WITHIN python (*basically print whatever Google says*). So, if the user inputs 'Python', I have to give the results for that from google.
I could do this this till now.

```
import webbrowser as wb
usrinput = input("Enter search query: ")
wb.open('https://www.google.co.in/?#q=' + usrinput)
```

I need to know how to print the result. Please help!

Comment: You should use a package such as [`xgoogle`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xgoogle) for this.

Comment: Alex: xgoogle doen not seem to work with Python 3.3 They have too many flaws in the GoogleSearch definition.

Comment: Scraping google is probably against its tos. It is remarkable that [google has no general search api](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/)